# All the facets terms not loading in multi list filter from solr on initial load

Tags: solr, content-search, sxa-search, search-facet

We are using `Sitecore 10.2` with SXA on Azure Kubernetes, and Solr as a search service.

On a multi-list facet filter (facet-multi-selection-list), trying to fetch facet terms, where facets are added under the path: `/sitecore/content/< tenantName>/< SiteName>/Settings/Facets`. But on loading the page, observed that all the facet terms not appearing from URL `//sxa/search/facets/?f=< Facetnames>`

Only if we are searching facets separately on the search box, it could be seen on the filter multi checklist.

**Note**: The indexer used here is a custom index, also the data is available correctly on the Solr index.

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.